# How to addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask for multi-touch gestures?

Tags: macos, cocoa, event-handling, multi-touch, nsevent

Everything works great - **locally** - with...

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskRotate 
                                      handler:^(NSEvent *e) {
                       NSLog(@"event type:  %lx", e.type);  }];
```

<kbd>NSLOG</kbd>`event type:  12`

However, I get NO gesture events in a global handler.. (although other types, scroll, click, etc DO work.)

```
_ev = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: NSEventMaskRotate 
                                             handler:^(NSEvent *e){
                             NSLog(@"event type:  %lx", e.type);  }];
```

<kbd>NSLOG</kbd>

This is under 10.8.  I realize gestures aren't goign to get reported on 10.6.. but the docs give no indication that this shouldn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've just tried doing this using EventTap too, and I can't get it to work. It used to work under 10.6 I think (based on source code on the web), but under 10.8 no luck :(

Comment: How ghetto.  Apple can be such an _arbitrary Nazi_, sometimes.